# How to reorder columns in gridview dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

Similar questions may exists, but none of them seems to be helpfull. So I'll try to explain a more specific case, and see if anyone can help me :)

Here is the thing, I have a gridview with templatefields, and I want to let the user to specify the order those columns are shown. So, the user creates a view and decides which column to display first, second, and so on.

So basically, I need to change the order of the columns just after the grid is loaded with data.

Sounds easy huh? Well, apparently it's not. At least I couldn't achieve that just yet.

Some notes:
- Of course I have AutogenerateColumns set to false.
- Change the sql select columns order won't work because of previous item.
- And I'd like not to generate the columns by the code.

Any ideas?

Comment: Here is how to reorder columns dynamically : http://stackoverflow.com/a/28611217/215752

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can modify the Gridview's Columns collection in your code-behind. So, one way of doing this is to remove the column from its current position in the collection and then re-insert it into the new position.

For example, if you wanted to move the second column to be the first column you could do:

```
var columnToMove = myGridView.Columns[1];
myGridView.Columns.RemoveAt(1);
myGridView.Columns.Insert(0, columnToMove);
```

If you need to move them all around randomly, then you might want to try to clone the field collection, clear the collection in the GridView, and then re-insert them all in the order you want them to be in.

```
var columns = myGridView.Columns.CloneFields();
myGridView.Columns.Clear();
myGridView.Columns.Add(columns[2]);
myGridView.Columns.Add(columns[0]);
etc..
```

I'm not 100% sure whether this all will work AFTER binding to data, so unless there's a reason not to, I'd do it in Page_Init or somewhere before binding.

Comment: That worked great! But just one thing... I have a button on that grid, where I apply some logic in OnRowCommand event. Well, now, after the rows are reordered, that method is never executed and also some of the columns are empty after I hit the button...

Comment: I've found using `myGridView.Columns.CloneFields();` makes a clone of all the column objects as well (which can be an issue). For example, if you have your own custom column that inherits from `BoundField` then it will clone your object to just a `BoundField`. To fix this, do: `myGridView.Columns.OfType<DataControlField>().ToList();` as this will just create a new collection while maintaining the references to the original column objects.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an really old question but the suggested answer did not solve the problem fully.

The ViewState for the GridView will failed after remove / add a dynamic column.

If you need to bind any event, like OnRowCommand and OnRowUpdating, such events will not be fired.

**Edit:**

Look into this function if you need answers.

```
Protected Overrides Function CreateColumns(dataSource As PagedDataSource, useDataSource As Boolean) As ICollection
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. We are not a discussion forum but question and answer. Please ensure your answers provide solutions to the original question. If there is another problem, please ask a new question.

Comment: Thanks. I simply do not have enough reputation to add a comment. If I do not state this out, other developers may run into bugs down the line.