# ASP.NET: How to allow reordering of gridview columns by user?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Does standard ASP.NET Gridview allow user to reorder columns at will?

If so, how do I implement this feature? Thanks.

Example: my gridview has 3 columns A, B and C. User 1 likes it to be arranged as B, C, A; user 2 likes C, A, B, and so on. I'd like the user to be able to drag the column header to his desired position if this feature is supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard `ASP.NET Gridview` does not support column ordering, unless you make a round-trip to the server and modify your data source.

You will have to implement the functionality by yourself or consider a third-party framework, such as **`Telerik's RadControls for ASP.NET AJAX`**. See a working example [here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/client/resizing/defaultcs.aspx).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8976153/how-to-reorder-columns-in-gridview-dynamically

Answer (score 1):

Caution: I didn't run this, but [this blog](http://forums.asp.net/t/1690911.aspx/1) refers to ordering the columns of your datatable (presumably datasource of the grid view) on the page_init and binding should handle the grid view column ordering... Now if you want to do it all async then it's just a longer conversation I think

Answer (score 1):

Take your data source as data table which you are going to bind to the grid view then, create new data table according to the user column order like

```
 DataTable SourceTable =  ds.Table[0];
 DataTable table1 = new DataTable("Employee"); 

\\ take user choice order in array and use loop to create column as per array
\\ Below is order your column you can also change this order according to your login
\\ put your login here to arrange column order 

 // this loop will create column according to user choice

 foreach(string row In USerChoiceArray)
 {
    table1.Columns.Add(row); 
 }



table1.Rows.Add(column value from source data table, 1); 
table1.Rows.Add(column value from source data table, 2);
```

now you have created data table according to user choice and bind this data table to the grid view as follows:

```
gridview.DataScource = table1 ;
gridview.DataBind();
```