# How i change order of my gridview columns dynamically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have an application in asp.net web .net.
this application have a collection of dogs and i can display this dog with specific criteria. 
For do this, i have one gridview bind to my dogs collection and i looking for how i can generate dynamically the order columns of my gridview using databinding.

Comment: Which brings up the question: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: i have try to bind the columns attribute but it's impossible.
i try to bind dynamically property of datafield,headertext of boundfield but it's impossible too.
So i try to find a way with bind ColumnsGenerator for the moment

Comment: This answer might help you : http://stackoverflow.com/a/28611217/215752

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a duplicate of this question.  The answer looks like it would help you: [How to reorder columns in gridview dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8976153/how-to-reorder-columns-in-gridview-dynamically)

You can use the `InsertAt`, `Remove` and `CloneFields` methods of `Gridview.Columns` to help you reorder columns.

Comment: If this is a duplicate question, please kindly flag it as **duplicate**. They'll vote to close it.