# How to change a datagridview's columns position and its index value?

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

Here i like to change columns position with its index value of my datagridview... i tried to change my column index with following suggested code,

```
      private void button17_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.Columns[0].DisplayIndex = 1;
        dataGridView1.Columns[1].DisplayIndex = 0;
        var head1 = dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText;
        var head2 = dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText;

         MessageBox.Show(head1,"column0");
         MessageBox.Show(head2,"column1");
    }
```

its just changing columns display position, but not the columns index value.. i have given my output screenshots here.

[image: Output1]

i need to interchange the positions with index of those two highlighted columns named as TIMESTAMP and WINDSPEEDHEIGHT1.

[image: Output2]

columns display position has been changed as above,

[image: Alert1]

[image: Alert2]

but still index value of column0 is TIMESTAMP and index value of column1 is WINDSPEEDHEIGHT1....

Can anyone help regarding interchanging the columns position with the index value..?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8976153/how-to-reorder-columns-in-gridview-dynamically

Comment: `dataGridView1.Columns["TIMESTAMP"].DisplayIndex = 1;`

Comment: From where you are assigning data source to the grid?. Using Query?

Comment: yes using query to import data from excel... OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
                        OleDbCommand oconn = new OleDbCommand("Select * From [" + textBox1.Text + "$]", con);

Comment: there only inter change the column know? what will happen if you do so? Means instead of * use column Name.

Answer (score 0):

Just switch the call on them in your query.