# Programmatically interchange rows in a datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want to interchange 2 rows in a datagridview based on the following condition

```
if (Convert.ToDateTime(gridview1["dChequeDate", i].Value) < Convert.ToDateTime(gridview1["dChequeDate", iVisibleIndex].Value))
{
}
```

Can somebody help me out with this?

Comment: You might want to do a semi bubble sort, just the technique :)

Comment: You can try this [link](http://goo.gl/jK4ieg). BTW,
A possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8976153/how-to-reorder-columns-in-gridview-dynamically)

Comment: What are the values of `gridview1["dChequeDate", i]` and `gridview1["dChequeDate", iVisibleIndex]` ? And you don't need to use `.Value` property.

Comment: Thanks for the link Dhruv Singh.It was very useful.But is it possible to swap rows without having to swap cell values.Kindly forgive me if this seems silly.I am just a rookie.

Comment: I'm not sure but I believe the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8976153/how-to-reorder-columns-in-gridview-dynamically) does the same thing.
Why are you swapping rows?; can't the functionality be done by sorting. As i see that you are trying to move rows according to date