# Positioning a TemplateField at specific column

Tags: asp.net, templatefield

i was created a TemplateField in code behind and it was added at the first column.
I want to add it to the last column.
How do i do that in code behind?

```
 TemplateField tf = new TemplateField();

 OrderGrid.Columns.Add(tf);
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually `GridView.Columns` collection has [Insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datacontrolfieldcollection.insert%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method defined, so you should be able to do this:

```
OrderGrid.Columns.Add(OrderGrid.Columns.Count - 1, tf);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below link..

[Changing Postion of Column in Gridview..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8976153/how-to-reorder-columns-in-gridview-dynamically)